# Show graph in tooltip of Highchart Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

How to create bar graph in tooltip of Highchart?
Problem is that I am unable to access dom element which is in tooltip html. the below console.log gives me undefined.

```
tooltip: {
   pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.0f}</b>',
   formatter: function(a) {
     var tooltipHtml;
     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(this.tooltipchart, "tooltipchart");
       
     }, 10);
    return tooltipHtml = '<div #tooltipchart></div>';
  },
```

},

Please guide me how to access dom element in this scenario? without jquery

Comment: To get DOM elements in Angular you would use the ViewChild and ViewChildren decorators. There are lots of post about this. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/querying-the-dom-with-@viewchild-and-@viewchildren

Comment: Please take a look at this example; https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6v8c3rhy/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thankyou, It's working like a charm!